# What does Finder (10.12) and IP Scanner require to run?

Tags: macos, finder, install

I am working on creating a macOS 10.12 Live USB, and need to know what /System/Library/Frameworks/ frameworks Finder and IP Scanner requires (and how do I install them/track all of their files down)?

I'm making a macOS 10.12 Live creator based on dosdude1's macOS Sierra Patcher, with a few changes (such as what gets moved onto the installer). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of a macOS USB Live? Running macOS installed on a USB drive you can run Finder just fine. Have you tried running Finder from e.g. the UI environment of a USB macOS Installer? If from a normal boot of macOS, you double-click Finder in Activity Monitor and select the Open File and Ports tab, you might get a better picture of whats needed. That said though, it may not be a complete picture.

Comment: My definition of macOS Live is just plugging in a thumbdrive, running macOS Live Creator, and then being able to boot from the usb from any mac (since I am not removing the booting patch from macOS Sierra Patcher).
Also, yes I have tried running Finder from a macOS Installer, it won't launch because of missing frameworks.

Comment: macOS Live Creator?

Comment: @user3439894 a variation of macOS Sierra Patcher by dosdude1

Comment: If macOS Live Creator is software you're developing, then it's are off-topic here, but can be asked on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).